# Difference between 接続 and つなぐ

Tags: nuances, wago-and-kango

In the context of connecting things, like a printer to a computer or a computer to the internet, is there a difference between these or are they interchangeable?

Answer (score 2):

Talking about physical connection, they are interchangeable.

- パソコンをプリンタ(インターネット)に接続する
- パソコンをプリンタ(インターネット)につなぐ

are both natural.

---

Non-interchangeable examples that come to my mind is つなぐ to mean introducing people and to pass phone calls (though this does not happen these days)

- Aさんにつないでほしい

can mean *Can you introduce me to A-san?* or *May I talk to A-san? (on the phone)*. Here 接続する(接続してほしい) cannot be used.